# Fieldsets Using Bootstrap Grids

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following markup using bootstrap grids:

```html
<form id="store-form" class="user-form">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <fieldset id="store-form-store-fields">
                <label>Store Nickname</label>
                <input id="store-nickname-field" type="text" name="nickname" required class="form-control">
            </fieldset>
        </div>

        <fieldset id="store-form-location-fields">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label>Store Address</label>
                <input id="store-street-field" type="text" name="street" required class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label>City</label>
                <input id="store-city-field" type="text" name="city" required class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label>State</label>
                <select id="store-state-field" name="state_id" required class="form-control">
                    <option>- Select a State -</option>
                    <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                    <option value="CA">California</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label>Zip Code</label>
                <input id="store-zipcode-field" type="text" name="zipcode" required class="form-control">
            </div>
        </fieldset>

    </div>

    <div class="submit-wrapper">
        <button id="store-form-submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit-button">Save</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

As you can see, I'm trying to use fieldsets to group the fields into two groups. I need to do this so that I can create Backbone.js view for each group of fields separately. Obviously this breaks the grid, since I have an immediate child of `.row` that isn't a column div.

Is there any way at all to make fieldsets work with a form that is layed out using Bootstrap grids?

Edit for clarification: My goal is for the layout to behave the same as if the fieldsets were removed from the example.

Answer (score 1):

What about wrapping the second `<fieldset>` in a `div.col-md-6` and putting all the contents of the second `<fieldset>` in `div.row`? That way you are not skipping the css column definition. Let me know if that helps.

UPDATE:

I modified the code to use responsive resets and `col-md-pull`/`col-sm-pull`. Seems to remain responsive. This may be closest solution possible as you would not be able to properly close the col definition `<div>` within that fieldset to get proper clearing.

http://jsfiddle.net/s9baun7c/4/

```
<form id="store-form" class="user-form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <fieldset id="store-form-store-fields">
                <label>Store Nickname</label>
                <input id="store-nickname-field" type="text" name="nickname" required class="form-control" />
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <fieldset id="store-form-location-fields">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <label>Store Address</label>
                <input id="store-street-field" type="text" name="street" required class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-sm-pull-12 col-sm-pull-12">
                        <label>City</label>
                        <input id="store-city-field" type="text" name="city" required class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
                    <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-12 col-sm-pull-12">
                        <label>State</label>
                        <select id="store-state-field" name="state_id" required class="form-control">
                            <option>- Select a State -</option>
                            <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                            <option value="CA">California</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-12 col-sm-pull-12">
                        <label>Zip Code</label>
                        <input id="store-zipcode-field" type="text" name="zipcode" required class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="submit-wrapper">
        <button id="store-form-submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit-button">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the entire second fieldset would be 6 columns wide. Even if the row wraps, it would wrap within the right-side 50% of the grid. [Here's an example](http://i746.photobucket.com/albums/xx104/buck4of4/Screen%20Shot%202015-07-13%20at%203.50.51%20PM_zpsdumiiod0.png). You can also reproduce this problem by expanding the width of the fiddle you posted. I'm looking for a way to semantically section off the form fields without changing the appearance of the 1-dimensional grid.

Comment: Are you looking for the second `<fieldset>` to be immediately underneath the first `<fieldset>` and span the whole row?

Comment: I guess I'm looking for the fieldsets to have no effect on the layout whatsoever. There wouldn't necessarily be a line break or visual distinction between them.

Comment: I'd make a new `div.row` > `div.col-md-12` and place that second `<fieldset>` within there. That will help ensure the bootstrap grid will have proper clearing and responsive capabilities, while taking up the entire row. Otherwise, you can utilize `col-sm-*`, `col-xs-*`, `col-lg-*` to control the exact structure at different viewports. Would you like me to update the answer to reflect that approach?

Comment: While always having the second fieldset on its own row would remove the need for a solution to this problem, it doesn't actually solve the problem. I'm looking for a way to have the grid respond as if there were no fieldsets at all. In my example, I need the first col in the second fieldset to be on the same row as the col in the first fieldset at sm size and above. I acknowledge that this may be impossible.